# reduce spacing in listliketab

Tags: itemize, tabbing

Does anybody have an elegant solution to controlling row height in a tabbed (non-enumerated) lists in LaTeX? *(The automatic line spacing I get is massive and takes up too much space.)*

I tried several options for the tabbing in lists and settled on listliketab since it seemed the promising, but I can't seem to control row height. Ideally I would like to customize everything (indentation, exact location of bullet point etc.) since I am merging it with sections created with another package that look slightly different.

I saw that itemize has added specifications such as [noitemsep], but itemize didn't take me very far. Is there a good way to do this with listliketab? Or should I use another package instead?

I've been through documentation, questions on this forum etc and I just can't find a fix. Would be immensely grateful for any pointers :)

```
\begin{listliketab}
\storestyleof{itemize}
    \begin{tabular}{Llll}
        \textbullet &  \textbf{~Data Analysis}:  & ~~~~~~R, Stata, Excel (Macros, VBA)   \\
        \textbullet &  \textbf{~Data Visualisation} & ~~~~~~R (ggplot / Shiny), Tableau \& Tableau Prep  \\
        \textbullet &  \textbf{~Qualitative Text Analysis}: & ~~~~~~Dedoose\\
        \textbullet &  \textbf{~Citation Management}: & ~~~~~~Zotero
    \end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Following the duplicate, you can use `\storestyleof{itemize} \bgroup \def\arraystretch{0.5} \begin{tabular} ...... \end{tabular} \egroup` to reduce the vertical spacing.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical spacing is not really the same, but here's how you can do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{zeroitemize}{\itemize[noitemsep]}{\enditemize}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\storestyleof{zeroitemize}%
\begin{listliketab}
\begin{tabular}{@{}Lll@{}}
  \textbullet & \textbf{Data Analysis}:  & R, Stata, Excel (Macros, VBA)   \\
  \textbullet & \textbf{Data Visualisation} & R (ggplot/Shiny), Tableau \& Tableau Prep  \\
  \textbullet & \textbf{Qualitative Text Analysis}: & Dedoose\\
  \textbullet & \textbf{Citation Management}: & Zotero
\end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
\item Data Analysis
\end{itemize}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

I didn't try solving the overfull line.

[image]

You may want to define a new environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{zeroitemize}{\itemize[noitemsep]}{\enditemize}
\newenvironment{cvitemize}[1]
 {\storestyleof{zeroitemize}\begin{listliketab}\begin{tabular}{L#1}}
 {\end{tabular}\end{listliketab}}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{cvitemize}{ll}
  \textbullet & \textbf{Data Analysis}:  & R, Stata, Excel (Macros, VBA)   \\
  \textbullet & \textbf{Data Visualisation} & R (ggplot/Shiny), Tableau \& Tableau Prep  \\
  \textbullet & \textbf{Qualitative Text Analysis}: & Dedoose\\
  \textbullet & \textbf{Citation Management}: & Zotero
\end{cvitemize}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
\item Data Analysis
\end{itemize}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```